# Nvidia Drivers and GPU

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, gpu

I've a laptop with an Nvidia optimus graphic card (**GEForce GT 630m**) with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. After a while of looking around, I found that the *optimus* controller for linus is **bumblebee**, so I installed it.

I would like to know whether is possible to perform GPU calculations using this driver, or Should I install the Nvidia driver? In a first try I installed the Nvidia driver, but it didn't work as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: Whats is you problem exactly? Your Unity 3D do not start?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switchable laptop graphics issues on Ubuntu 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160242/switchable-laptop-graphics-issues-on-ubuntu-12-04/160310)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed bumblebee, you should already be using the Nvidia driver when calling the program with the `optirun` prefix. There is a difference though between using the GPU for applications that use the Nvidia driver and using it for CUDA. Apparently, for CUDA, bumblebee is not needed, but you need to install the CUDA relevant packages.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to find out how to install the CUDA packages. :-)