# Is somehow possible to run Ubuntu with both graphics?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

Is somehow possible to run Ubuntu with both graphics cards like in Windows ? I tested Linux Mint and he recognized both graphic cards and at details about my computer it was showing them both, but in Ubuntu only shows Intel (integrated).I like Ubuntu and I wish I could use both cards on it because I need power on video and photo editing. I apologize if the question is stupid, I'm new in the Linux world.

My computer (Acer 5755g from 2011) details are :

```
Procesor      : Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
Ram           : 8 GB
Video         : Nvidia 540m 2gb and Intel (integrated)
Hdd           : 650 GB.
OS            : Ubuntu 13.04 the 64 bit version.
```

Comment: according to the info you posted, both graphic cards are found by Ubuntu. "Video         : **Nvidia 540m 2gb** and Intel (integrated)"  If this is a Optimus hybrid see [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/167402/65969) question.  if you need to install Nvidia's proprietary drivers see [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/47506/65969)

Comment: I posted my computer componets because I thought it may be helpful, Ubuntu only finds Intel graphic card.

Comment: oh ok, I thought that that was what Ubutnu was telling you not just the computer specs. In that case you likely have a Optimus video card.  [Here](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/65969) is a better question about Optimus and how to get it working.  I don't use it so I can't help other than to try to direct you to an answer.