# Ubuntu 14.04,NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [NVS 5400M] laptop monitor problem

Tags: 14.04, laptop, lenovo, monitor, nvidia-optimus

I am having a problem with making the laptop monitor work with the latest ubuntu. I am using optimus on lenovo t430 at the moment and when I try to activate the laptop monitor I get an extended virtual screen on which all my windows are also stretched and it looks like this:
http://screencloud.net/v/eee6 I tried using different drivers but with no avail. It only worked with the open source driver but then the mouse pointer was dissapearing, animations where choppy etc. etc.
These are my installed drivers at the moment http://screencloud.net/v/bwtm, even withouth the xorg-edgers repo I got the same results. It was working fine in 13.10.

Thanks.

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/162639/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-recognize-my-nvidia-graphics-card

Answer (score 0):

I have been instances like that.

- Open System Setting and open Display (It symbol is computer screen).
- On pop-up windows, It has two squares (Built-in Display and Unknown Display)
- Select Unknown Display and turn off it.

Comment: Well the thing is that I don't want to turn it off, I want to use my laptop monitor:)

Comment: Virtual screen that you mention is Unknown display. Turn off it will not affect you.

Comment: It's already turned off, as I said previously if I turn it on it stretches my screen, maybe there's something in nvidia-settings that is messing the conf.