# How do I install the video driver on an Asus N56V?

Tags: 12.04, asus, nvidia-optimus

On a fresh installation of Kubuntu 12.04 amd64 on a Asus N56V jockey-kde says that there are no useful prprietary drivers.

Using the info-center I can see

in PCI an Nvidia Non-VGA unclassified device (0x00)

in Opengl an Intel Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller

=======================================================================

I've found that the 3.2 kernel is missing many kernel modules for
the Asus N56V machine and other ivy-bridge machines.

The machine is also overheating.

I'm closing this thread and I'll start a new one after installing
12.10 alpha 2 that uses a 3.5 kernel

=======================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) packaged drivers for your video card because Nvidia does not yet officially support these for Linux. See this thread for further instructions: [Switchable laptop graphics issues on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160242/switchable-laptop-graphics-issues-on-ubuntu-12-04/160310)

Comment: I have a 650M card that seems giving issues. For now I'll leave with the intel graphic: i'm in hurry to be operational on this machine. Thanks.