# Switching between Intel and NVIDIA GPU

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, gpu

My laptop has 2 GPUs, the Intel HD Graphics 4000, and NVIDIA GeForce FT 650M. How do I switch between GPUs? I tried installing drivers from NVIDIA, but that ruined my Ubuntu installation, and I had to reinstall. The Additional Drivers in Settings don't list any Nvidia drivers either.

Comment: I thought I had ruined my fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 with installing the latest video drivers from NVida, then I came across this site: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-the-Latest-NVIDIA-331-20-Drivers-in-Ubuntu-13-10-399182.shtml The command line was a mess trying to install the latest drivers. As far as switching back and fourth would mean, correct me if I'm wrong here, just a change to the xorg.conf to point x to the other driver. Anyway I hope this is helpful. The PPA in that link is awesome guys over there to put the code injection for your current kernel version for the n

Answer (score 1):

Your graphics card is not yet officially supported by Nvidia, and requires the bumblebee drivers for Linux. You can find more information on this post: [Switchable laptop graphics issues on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160242/switchable-laptop-graphics-issues-on-ubuntu-12-04/160310#160310)

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly easier to use: [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/7-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html)

Just go to part 4, about graphics switching.

Also, take a ook at this more detailed explanation, also at WebUpd8:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/bumblebee-31-released-with-primus.html

Comment: Please don't just link to an external site; Include all the usefull informations. Links rot.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the latest driver from nVidia's website and allow executing it and you are good to go.

Answer (score -2):

This is way outdated!!

Google

For Switching

Log out and back in
    nvidia-prime (best)  Solid

On the Fly

Bumblebee (still problematic and difficult/tedious to install)

Trying to help Mark

p.s a new CLI (terminal) way to install your latest Drivers is

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: I'm sorry but please put a bit more effort in explaining what you suggest. I don't understand any of it.