# (How) can I enable automatic switching between Intel and NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, intel, gpu

I'm using a PC with an integrated Intel and a dedicated NVIDIA GPU. Is there a way to switch between the two graphics adapters automatically - depending upon the need at the moment?
Using the NVIDIA settings application forces me to log out and back in to perform the switch.

[image]

I found a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195972/switching-between-intel-and-nvidia-gpu), but the answers are not sufficient enough. I installed [bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/a/160310/417607), but I don't want to specify the card each time when I run a program. Is there an automatical solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately as of today automatically switching between the intel and NVIDIA graphics is still not supported on Linux based operating systems. There is some progress to be seen in GNOME 3.22, where it is possible to launch an application with the dedicated graphics adapter, but only when the open source drivers are in use. Maybe this feature will be available for the proprietary drivers in the future. In the meantime, for Ubuntu I recommend to use the default solution `nvidia-prime` and to remove `bumblebee`, because this software is not maintained any longer ... the latest version **3.2.1** was released on **April, 26th in 2013** -> [Bumblebee Version 3.2.1 "Tumbleweed" - Release Notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/master/doc/RELEASE_NOTES_3_2_1) !

Example of GNOME 3.22 - most probably the version which will ship with Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 :

[image]

We will see how this will influence the development of other Ubuntu editions and graphics drivers.

Comment: 1. Is it still true that Linux-based systems don't have this automatic switch?
2. As I understood, this feature in gnome you are referring to, will only allow me to use dedicated graphics, but it will still be completely manual, I got it right?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić 1. Correct, there still is no automatic switch available in Linux. 2. When you use the open source nouveau drivers, you are using the intel graphics by default and you alternatively can launch an application with the dedicated graphics ... it is built-in and works out-of-the-box. When you install the NVIDIA drivers, you are always running the dedicated graphics chip. Tools like bumblebee are more or less a "hack".

Comment: +1 please revisit in 6 months or so with a status update.

Comment: Is this still the state of the art on the matter?

Comment: @Rodriguez : Switching between intel and NVIDIA automatically is still not supported on Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script which makes easier to switch between intel and nvidia's graphics cards and besides it fixes screen tearing bug on Intel's. If you are interested in check it out: [Graphics-Switcher](https://github.com/bauca/graphics-switcher)