# Crash after modifying rc.local file to solve overheating issue

Tags: kernel, power-management

I made a dual boot on my laptop with Windows 8. After installing Ubuntu, I notices that my laptop was really hot, and realized that both GPUs are working, my integrated Intel GPU and secondary NVidia. I found this solution 
http://techhamlet.com/2012/05/ubuntu-how-to-fix-over-heating-of-laptops-with-switchable-graphics/
and it really helped me, my computer stopped overheating instantly. But after some time, whenever I try to reboot, or work on my computer, it freezes, and on version 12.04.4 I wasn't even able to reboot it, it just froze on black screen saying something about kernel, nouveau, didn't really manage to remember all.
Any suggestions? I think that it would work without changing rc.local, but I really don't want my computer to overheat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think that I solved this issue. I was researching a lot, and I found this: [Switchable laptop graphics issues on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160242/switchable-laptop-graphics-issues-on-ubuntu-12-04/160310#160310)

I did this, I can feel that my laptop stopped overheating instantly after reboot, and I don't have any problems with booting Ubuntu. Also, there is another link that you could check if you have this problem: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

So the solution would be to install bumblebee. If I encounter any more problems, I will edit this post.

Answer (score 2):

Linux now supports Hybrid Graphics Systems. For Nvidia Hybrid Graphics you need following packages.

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime`

you can find a review about the working and functioning of the Nvidia Hybrid Graphics on Ubuntu on [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/8-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html).[image]

Comment: Wow I searched for two days and never saw this. Thank you very much, I will try this as soon as I come home from work.

Comment: @grayFox did you reverted the changes to the rc.local?

Comment: No I couldn't as ubuntu did not want to boot. So I am installing it again

Comment: Ok I installed this but cannot find the option to switch GPUs..

Comment: I have not personally tested it. But now I will do a bit more research on it.